# What is the best way to deal with co-dependent classes in C++?

Tags: c++, header

Say I have a class foo with an object of class bar as a member

```
class foo
{
    bar m_bar;
};
```

Now suppose bar needs to keep track of the foo that owns it

```
class bar
{
    foo * m_pfoo;
}
```

The two classes reference each other and without a forward declaration, will not compile. So adding this line before foo's declaration solves that problem

```
class bar;
```

Now, here is the problem - when writing the header files, each *header* depends on the other: foo.h needs the definitions in bar.h and vice-versa. What is the proper way of dealing with this?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You need to move all of the member access out of the header, and into your source files.

This way, you can forward declare your classes in the header, and define them in foo:

```
// foo.h
class bar;

class foo {
    bar * m_pbar;
}

// bar.h
class foo;
class bar {
    foo * parent;
}
```

That will allow you to work - you just can't put definitions that require member information into your header - move it to the .cpp file.  The .cpp files can include both foo.h and bar.h:

```
// Foo.cpp
#include "foo.h"
#Include "bar.h"

void foo::some_method() {
     this->m_pbar->do_something(); // Legal, now, since both headers have been included
}
```

Comment: This seems like the best option for what I need.

Comment: now how does this solution work if your codependent classes are templated, and so can't be separated into header and cpp files?

Answer (score 3):

I suppose one way is to make abstract interface classes with no members. Then subclass foo and bar from those interface classes.

e.g.:

```
class FooInterface
{
   // methods here
}

class BarInterface
{
   // methods here
}

class Foo : public FooInterface
{
   BarInterface *pBar;
}

class Bar : public BarInterface
{
   FooInterface *pFoo;
}
```

This breaks the cycle of dependencies (unless the interfaces themselves depend on each other, and if that's the case then they should probably be declared in the same file)

Answer (score 2):

In your example, `foo` depends on `bar` (because it contains an actual `bar` object), but `bar` does not depend on `foo` (since it only contains a `foo *`).  Now `bar` does depend on on `foo` being a type name, so bar.h needs a forward declaration of the name: `class foo;`.  `foo` depends on `bar`, so foo.h should contain `#include "bar.h"`

You can't have classes that directly depend on each other in C++; it simply doesn't work.  You need to decouple the classes such that one only depends on the other existing, like in your example.  The only things that create a direct dependence are using a class as a base class or as a field; any other use just creates an indirect dependence, which is generally not a problem.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the only real way of doing this is using pointers since they don't require class definition until the translation unit (.cpp) in which case both classes will have been defined properly.