# C++ - Best convention to resolve templated classes' circular dependencies in header files?

Tags: c++, graph, header-files, circular-dependency

I am writing my own implementation of a templated `Graph` class in C++ and so I am also implementing templated `Vertex` and `Edge` classes.  Thus, the implementations have to be inside their respective header file and not inside separate `.cpp` files.  (The top answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2143714/what-is-the-best-way-to-deal-with-co-dependent-classes-in-c) won't work for me)

My `Vertex` class stores an adjacency list of out-edges as a `vector` of `Edge`s and the `Edge` class stores pointers to the source and destination `Vertex`s as well as the weight of the edge.

Since `Edge` only stores pointers to `Vertex`, it is sufficient to forward declare the `Vertex` class in `Edge.h`.  Then I can `#include "Edge.h"` at the top of `Vertex.h`.

Is this the best way to resolve the co-dependencies of the `Vertex` and `Edge` classes? The user will have to `#include` both files in order to use either one (i.e. in `Graph.h`).

What if users want to use `Vertex` without having to also explicitly include `Edge.h` or vice versa?  Should I forward declare and `#include` each inside the other?

Or should I implement them in the same header file?

How, if at all, is this problem addressed in STL?

Here's what I have right now:

Edge.h:

```
#ifndef _EDGE_H__
#define _EDGE_H__

template <class T> class Vertex;

template <class T>
class Edge
{
private:
    Vertex<T>* _source;
    Vertex<T>* _dest;
    unsigned long long _weight;

...

};
#endif
```

Vertex.h:

```
#ifndef _VERTEX_H__
#define _VERTEX_H__
#include "Edge.h"
#include <vector>

template <class T>
class Vertex
{
private:
    std::vector<Edge<T> > _adj;

...

};
#endif
```

Comment: I'm not sure it's the best design to have a vertex own the edges. Rather, I'd probably have the Graph own both.

Comment: Always strive to minimize coupling. As you have already succeeded, you are done. Though it is a valid contention to say that you will need both anyway iff you need either, so separating them is just too much work for no gain...

Comment: Also, don't use `_EDGE_H__` etc. as your include guard macro names. They are reserved.

Comment: @T.C. What would you recommend as a guard instead ? It is more useful when the **do this** instead of only saying **don't do this*.

Comment: @localhost "Use a name that's [not reserved](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier/228797#228797)"?

Comment: @T.C. This still does not answer the other part, particularly instead use *this* or "Here is an example, use something like **this**". For example, what would you use as a guard with the code above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have come up with a compromise for a solution by decoupling the `Vertex` class from the `Edge` class as follows.

Edge.h:

```
#ifndef EDGE_H
#define EDGE_H

template <class T> class Edge
{
private:
    T* _source;
    T* _dest;
    long long _weight;

...

};
#endif
```

And in `Vertex.h` the vector becomes `std::vector<Edge<Vertex<T> > >`. That can be simplified, if desired, with a public `typedef Edge<Vertex<T> > Edge` in both `Vertex.h` and `Graph.h`.  Thus the circular dependence is eliminated and each class can be used "separately" without including the other explicitly: now `Graph.h` depends on `Vertex.h` which depends on `Edge.h`.

As a side note to address comments regarding a vertex that owns its out-edges: I am expanding an already complete implementation of a graph class I wrote and the algorithms will be plug-and-play (with minimal changes) only if I keep the same/similar adjacency-list structure.

Answer (score 0):

> What if users want to use Vertex without having to also explicitly include Edge.h or vice versa?

Since you're essentially talking about designing a `Graph` class in the first place, there's nothing bad in including both of the headers **inside** it. The user would then just `#include "graph.h"` (or whatever you call the file), not really carring about how it's designed on the lower level.

That being said - if you want to keep your class designed the way it is at the moment - your solution is a good idea. However, as mentioned already in the comments, there's no need for a Vertex to own its edges. Maybe you should consider a different structure:

```
template<typename vertexType, typename edgeType>
class graph{
    std::map<std::pair<vertexType,vertexType>, edgeType>;
};
```

Keep in mind that with this design, the particular methods will probably be a bit more complex to write (and probably a bit slower). However - you'll end up using far less memory in the process. Depending on what you really want to achieve (either small size or fast work), you may end up using a different graph structure.

Comment: My implementation of `Graph` is optimizing for speed over space, so this structure is undesirable.

Comment: @pdpiech I don't think the speed will make that much of a difference. I've used that structure in my game engine (pathfinding), and it didn't slow things even a bit (even with 20+ units on the map with 50 nodes). Anyhow - there's no real way to solve the circular dependencies other than what you did.